# How/why was the slow motion coin shot achieved in Scrooged?

Tags: production, film-techniques, scrooged

In the movie Scrooged, one of the main themes of the show is the airing of a live broadcast of the movie/play "A Christmas Carol".

During the later parts of the live broadcast, Scrooge tossed a coin to a boy in the street to go buy "The biggest goose in all of London". As the camera follows the coin, it is flipping and falling in slow motion.

How would this effect be achieved in a live broadcast, and why would it be done (as opposed to the coin just being shown falling and tumbling as normal)?

Answer (score 1):

The question is tricky because there is the movie (*Scrooged*) and the TV show within the movie. I believe the slow-motion effect was for the audience watching *Scrooged*, to show something magical happening. (IIRC, the slow-motion coin is caught by Frank, and acts as the transition from the TV show to the "real" world depicted in which Frank has had a revelation.)

Comment: Yes, Frank did catch it and break the 4th wall doing so. But, the *tv show* in the movie is portrayed as "live", and IIRC the directors on set are saying something like "Ok, follow the coin", and it's shown in slow motion.

Comment: Exactly how I remember it. I was thinking that the slow motion was shown from the point of view of the _Scrooged_ movie, rather than the filmmakers implying that the coin was flying slowly within the TV show they were shooting. (It's hard to describe because of the movie reality vs. the TV show within it!)